# Laravel + Inertia + Vue basic setup Error: Cannot find module './Event/Show'

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

Have followed the official tutorial for server side and client side setup

https://inertiajs.com/server-side-setup

But getting the above error in Browser console

Here is the code repository to get straightforward to the point

https://github.com/sbaum2s/inertia_laravel_8_demo

Comment: https://github.com/sbaum2s/inertia_laravel_8_demo leads to 404.
Also you should create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @ericmp its up again and yes, it is a minimal example.